# Populate a column in a junction table Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, junction-table

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship.
The relevant part of the tables look like this:

```
Filmlager [ProgramID, Type]

Genre [GenreID, GenreTitle]
```

Since there's a many-to-many relationship I've created a junction table looking like this:

```
ProgramGenre [ProgramID, GenreID, GenreOrder]
```

Now I want to set the value 1 in the `GenreOrder` column where `Filmlager.Type=Genre.GenreTitle`

So far I've managed to get the ProgramID and GenreID where I want to update the GenreOrder by using the following query:

```
 SELECT p.ProgramID, p.GenreID
 FROM ProgramGenre p, Filmlager f, Genre g
 WHERE p.ProgramID = f.ProgramID
 AND p.GenreID = g.GenreID
 AND f."Type"= g.GenreTitle;
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. The part I can't figure out is how to compare the combination of two columns (the result from the query above) with ProgramID and GenreID in the ProgramGenre table. I've tried using nested queries without success.

I'm using Transact-SQL in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do an update:

```
UPDATE p SET GenreOrder = 1
FROM ProgramGenre p
JOIN Filmlager f ON p.ProgramID = f.ProgramID
JOIN Genre g ON p.GenreID = g.GenreID
WHERE f."Type"= g.GenreTitle;
```